# Why does my website try to GET Sass file?

Tags: sass

In my website, I am only including the `.css` files that are generated by SASS. However, when I inspect the Network tab in Chrome I can see the browser is trying to GET the `.map` and `.scss` files as well. The `.map` file works, but the `.scss` is failing because of the file type being not allowed in my server configuration.

Are these files supposed to be loaded as well? I would expect only the CSS is needed.. these others are just used in the compilation side.

Here is my line of code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mywebapp/SASS/maas.css" />
```

When I exclude it, the browser GETs none of these files, but adding it causes it to GET all 3... I'm very confused about what is initializing these requests.

If this is NOT supposed to happen by default then there must be something set up in our CMS that is forcefully requesting these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find in your CSS something like this `/*# sourceMappingURL=/mywebapp/SASS/maas.css.map */`

maas.css.map tries to read you `.scss`

You can read - http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass

Comment: Yes, but that line is commented out at the time it gets to the client so why would this create a new GET request?  Is this expected behavior? Should the client always GET the .map and .scss files?

Comment: But you are right cause I take that comment out and it no longer pulls in the .map file.. what is the point of trying to GET the .map and scss files? The client doesn't even care about those

Comment: Ok so source maps are only really needed for debugging? I compile my SASS with Koala and "Source Maps" is checked by default.. If I remove that and re-compile it appears to work.  And I see now that source maps are a standard at the Browser level and can be configured via the browser. Thanks

Comment: @MattHintzke, yes, just for debugging.